# Bash $@ outputs

Tags: bash

I dont understand the behaviour of the builtin Bash variables very good.

I have this small test script:

```
arg1="$@"
arg2=("$@")
echo "$@"
echo "arg with parenthesis = $arg2"
echo "arg without parenthesis = $arg1"
```

I execute it like that:
`bash test.sh argument1 argument2`

And I get this output:

```
Test argurments
argument1 argument2
arg with parenthesis = argument1
arg without parenthesis = argument1 argument2
```

Can someone explain to me why I only get argument1 when the $@ is referenced in parenthesis?

Comment: Parentheses means array. So arg2 is an array of `(argument1, argument2)`. When you access an array without an index it pretends it's a variable of just the first element. Generally speaking `"$@"` should expand to `"argument1" "argument2"`, but if it did then arg1 shouldn't behave this way, so I don't know what that's about.

Comment: Look what they write about `$@` in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters). It behaves differently based on whether it's "In contexts where word splitting is performed". So that's why it behaves different in arg1 assignment than you expect.

Comment: To get all the items of arg2 : `echo "arg with parenthesis = ${arg2[@]}"`

Comment: `echo` is a bad tool for this job. You'll get much more informative differences by comparing `printf '%s\n' "${arg1[@]}"` and `printf '%s\n' "${arg2[@]}"`; or perhaps `declare -p arg1 arg2`